# Graph Theory: Degree of regions in a planar graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

**-Background Information:**

I am studying graph theory in discrete mathematics. As I was reading my notes, I came across an example provided by my professor that I am confused about. I need some clarification to understand it better, thanks.

---

**- Definition & Example:**

[image]

---

**- Question:**

If I start at a vertex and an edge and go all the way to around R2 and come back, should I pass the same edge and end the same vertex? (I assume each edge that connects two components is a bridge and a bridge counts as two edges).

Could you please see my thinking section down below, am I right with the way I solved the problem?

---

**- My thinking:**

Consider each bridge to have two arrows indicating two edges.

[image]

In this case, I traverse 14 edges, so the degree of R4 is 14, am I right? Is this the way to do it?

If yes, why not using the other (green) edge, using that edge can give us a shorter closed walk of 12? (considering you go and come back from that edge).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to count each edge bordering the region:

[image]

Comment: Ok but what you are saying is opposite of what @Hagen von Eitzen is saying, I mean aren't we supposed to count each bridge twice? You did only once.

Comment: Notice the two edges that were counted twice.

Comment: oh, I see yeah that makes sense now. I didn't know what bordering exactly meant in the question, so now it is clear. I completely understand it now,thanks a lot :)

Comment: Imagine walking the path (1-2-...-13-14).  The steps 3 and 4 counted one edge twice and the steps 6 and 13 counted another edge twice (these are the bridges).

Comment: Interesting, I was thinking of this pattern at first, 1, 2, 5, 6,6, 7,  8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 13, 5, 2, 1. But now bordering makes sense, it has to pass all edges, so only 3, 4 and 6, 13 are the bridges. I guess I was misunderstanding it at first.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are $6+4$ "normal" edges bordering $R4$ and $2$ bridges, giving $10+2\cdot 2=14$.

Comment: Ok, I see, and @Hagen von Eitzen did u consider the bridges the same as the one I have 4 arrows on it?

Comment: Could you please also explain why not use the edge that the green arrow is pointing to? I mean using that edge for going and coming back will reduce the degree of 14 to 12. This is what we want because we are looking for the length of the shortest close walk.